# show loading screen to user when lazy loading vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading

i am making lazy loading features for my spa vue js using laravel mix 5

and right now i want to know how to show something maybe like a loading page so my apps not hang while the apps is loading new page.

i tried to add this

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- header -->
    <transition 
        enter-active-class="animated fadeInDown"
        leave-active-class="animated fadeOutUp"
        mode="out-in"
    >
        <router-view name="header"></router-view>
    </transition>
    
    <!-- body -->
    <transition 
        enter-active-class="animated fadeIn"
        leave-active-class="animated fadeOut"
        mode="out-in"
    >
        <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
    
</div>
</template>
```

i thought it will do fadeOut animation while waiting for the new page loaded. But in practice my app screen not doing animation and feels like the apps is hang (but button still working).

so what i imagine is maybe when user click to navigate new page then while the page being loaded  then i want to remove or hide current page to indicate something is working and user not tapping  button multiple time thinking the web is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

okay after doing some more in depth searching i finally found the solution

first you need to use vuex to pass along the variable or information and then you just hook it into router function like this

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=>{
  store.commit('setLoading', true)
  next()
})
router.afterEach((to, from)=>{
  store.commit('setLoading', false)
})
```

and then in my `app.vue` files i just add this

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- header -->
    <transition 
        enter-active-class="animated fadeInDown"
        leave-active-class="animated fadeOutUp"
        mode="out-in"
    >
        <router-view name="header"></router-view>
    </transition>
    
    <!-- body -->
    <transition 
        enter-active-class="animated fadeIn"
        leave-active-class=""
        mode="out-in"
    >
        <loading-page v-if="isLoading"></loading-page>
        <router-view v-else></router-view>
    </transition>
    
</div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
    import loadingPage from "./views/loading.vue";

    export default {
        components: {
            loadingPage
        },
        computed:{
            ...mapGetters('global',{
                isLoading: 'isLoading'
            }),
        },
    }
</script>
```

and here is my loading screen, just a simple page with loading bar

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- page container -->
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content">

                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width: 100%">
                                <span class="sr-only">100% Complete</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</template>
```

and for my vuex

```
export const global = {
  namespaced: true,
  
  // state
  state: {
    isLoading: '',
  },

  // getters
  getters: {
    isLoading: state => state.isLoading,
  },

  // actions
  actions: {

    // change data
    setLoading({commit}, type){
      commit('setLoading', type);
    },
  },

  // mutations
  mutations: {

    setLoading ( state, type ){
      state.isLoading = type;
    },
  }
}
```

then it will be just showing that loading screen whenever i navigate to other page that still not yet be loaded in user browser.